# Jupyter lab - kernel keeps dying

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I'm fairly new to Python in general so everything is an uphill struggle. I'm analyzing a large number of documents. I was struggling to process them all at once, so I've split them into 5 batches generating a .txt file for each output. I'm now trying to merge them together and save everything into a .json file, but the code I wrote keeps failing causing the kernel to die. I have no idea how to solve this

This is the code I'm using right now

```
import os

default_path = "/Users/omitted/Desktop/Python/"
os.chdir(default_path)

first_batch = "Data/5_json/output_1.txt"
central_batches = "Data/5_json/output_2.txt", "Data/5_json/output_3.txt", "Data/5_json/output_4.txt"
last_batch = "Data/5_json/output_5.txt"


#Opening batch
with open(first_batch, 'r+') as part_1:
    data_1 = part_1.read()
    string_list_1 = list(data_1)
    string_list_1[-1] = ","
    new_string_1 = "".join(string_list_1)


#Central batch
mid_string = ""
for file in central_batches:
    with open(file, "r+") as part_2:
        data_2 = part_2.read()
        string_list_2 = list(data_2)
        string_list_2[0] = " "
        new_string_2 = "".join(string_list_2)

        new_string_list_2 = list(new_string_2)
        new_string_list_2[-1] = ","
        final_string_2 = "".join(new_string_list_2)
        
        mid_string += final_string_2

        
#Closing batch
with open(last_batch, 'r+') as part_5:
    data_5 = part_5.read()
    string_list_5 = list(data_5)
    string_list_5[0] = " "
    new_string_5 = "".join(string_list_5)

#Merge batches
merge = new_string_1 + mid_string + new_string_5
merge_destring = eval(merge)

import json
file_path = "Data/5_json/output_final.json"
with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(merge_destring, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Edit: the `merge_destring = eval(merge)` part seems to be the point where everything gets stuck, but if I skip that and save the 'merge' directly a " gets added to the beginning and end of the json file. Any other way to achieve the same result?

Edit2: I tried also `ast.literal_eval()`, which results in the same problem, and `json.loads()` which results in an error message: "JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)". The reason why I'm doing it this way is that I wasn't able to figure out how to merge the json files otherwise. This is how my .json files are structured:

```
{
    "TFU_1881_00102": {
        "magazine": "edited out",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "year": "1881",
        "tokens": [
            "batch",
            "different",
            "word",
            "like",
            "religion",
            "secularization",
            "understand",
            "mention",
            "religion"
        ],
        "bigramFreqs": {
            "batch different": 1,
            "different word": 1,
            "word like": 1,
            "like religion": 1,
            "religion secularization": 1,
            "secularization understand": 1,
            "understand mention": 1,
            "mention religion": 1,
            "religion religion": 1
        },
        "tokenFreqs": {
            "batch": 1,
            "different": 1,
            "word": 1,
            "like": 1,
            "religion": 2,
            "secularization": 1,
            "understand": 1,
            "mention": 1
        }
    },
    "TFU_1881_00103": {
        "magazine": "edited out",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "year": "1881",
        "tokens": [
            "religion",
            "religion",
            "religion",
            "properly",
            "count",
            "religion"
        ],
        "bigramFreqs": {
            "religion religion": 2,
            "religion properly": 1,
            "properly count": 1,
            "count religion": 1,
            "religion time": 1
        },
        "tokenFreqs": {
            "religion": 4,
            "properly": 1,
            "count": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Edit3: Ok, so I found a workaround. The following code worked for me:

```
import json
f = open("Data/5_json/output_1.json")
data = json.load(f)
f2 = open("Data/5_json/output_2.json")
data2 = json.load(f2)
f3 = open("Data/5_json/output_3.json")
data3 = json.load(f3)
f4 = open("Data/5_json/output_4.json")
data4 = json.load(f4)
f5 = open("Data/5_json/output_5.json")
data5 = json.load(f5)

data_final = data | data2 | data3| data4 | data5

file_path = "Data/5_json/output_final.json"
with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(data_final, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

For some reason, whenever I loop through `json.load()` using `with open() as i`, it returns an error.

Comment: if you have answered your own question, post the answer as a separate answer and not part of the original question.